# Is ChannelOutboundInvoker.flush() a synchronous / blocking call?

Tags: netty

Is it safe to reuse (the byte array wrapped by) a ByteBuf directly after a call to `ChannelOutboundInvoker.flush()` or `ChannelOutboundInvoker.writeAndFlush()`?

```
byte[] bytes = ...
ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);
ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBuf);
bytes[0] = 0; // safe to do here?
```

I have tried this dozens of times and it was fine every time, but I want to know whether it is *guaranteed* to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not safe / fine as it is not guaranteed to be executed right away. The only "safe" way to do this is to re-use the `byte[]` once the `ChannelFuture` completes that is returned by `writeAndFlush(...)`.

Something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ...
ByteBuf byteBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(bytes);
ctx.writeAndFlush(byteBuf).addListener(f -> {
    bytes[0] = 0;
});
```

Comment: Oops. I guess I should have considered the return value... Thanks for clearing this up. Plus, this way it's not blocking, but still safe. Perfect!